# How to disable logging rejected files in the .bad file?

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have a few instances of the same PowerCenter session running in parallel. They attempt to insert a large number of rows into the same target table. The table has a unique constraint on the natural key columns that causes a lot of rows to be rejected due to unique constraint violation. These rows are saved in a reject file and it hurts the performance of the entire process.

I don't need a list of rejected rows - it was my conscious decision to prevent the duplicate rows on the database level, not in the mapping. This is a known side effect of this design decision.

Is there a setting to prevent the rejected rows from being logged in a reject file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While PowerCenter provides no setting to disable the reject file and leaving `Reject Filename` empty causes an error, there is a nice workaround - you can use the [null device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device) to *save* the rejected rows (and *saving* means discarding all data written to a null device but reporting that the write operation succeeded).

If the Integration Service is running on Linux, you can use `/dev/null` - set the appropriate target settings as follows:

```
Reject File Dir: /dev/
Reject Filename: null
```

Windows equivalent of `/dev/null` is the `NUL` file. I have not tested with a PowerCenter session but `C:\some\directory\NUL` should work fine.